# How to copy rows from table variable into a normal table in MS SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a sql query wherein the output(rows) of my query are gathered in a table variable named "@Data" and the number of rows generated as output are around 50000. How can I copy those rows in to a table which is present in my SQL database? I am using MS SQL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A simple insert into table select should do it. like this`INSERT INTO table(<columnlist>) SELECT <columnList> FROM @Data`

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into <your table name> (
    <columns>
)
select
    <columns>
from @Data
```

As a side note, using table variables with number of rows ~50K usually do not gives you good performance, you can consider [temporary tables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186986(v=sql.105).aspx) instead